# How to send html email what to avoid and what not to include?

Tags: html, email, zend-framework

Many email clients (world wide target) example: Yahoo/Gmx/Google/Open source webmails + Microsoft Outlook oldest to latest 2011 + Mozilla email client + Other Linux email clients , you can just name it......

Does not render my HTML code same as it would show in the web browser while designing or coding. Even few email clients completely put it as SPAM/Junk etc etc.

After sending to someone either head or body or legs are broken.... just simply you can say give up its not working...

## Question:

For E-Mail, what Html to avoid in template as you can see below, i included almost what i got. Can a email template contain DOCTYPE/META/TITLE/SCRIPT/HEAD/HTML/BODY/DIV/TABLE/P/STRONG/B etc etc ?

What is the best practice for HTML E-mail?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet('/css/page.css'); ?>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/pageicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="SITE Page"
      href="/rss.xml" />

        <style type="text/css">
            body {  color:#525252; } 
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

      <div>
          <a href="http://www.site.com">
              <img src="http://www.site/log.gif" alt=""/>
          </a>
      </div>

      <img width="881" src="http://www.site.com/fashion.png" alt=""/>


      <div class="content"> <?= $this->layout()->content; ?> </div>


    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find some detailed info at the [email standards project](http://www.email-standards.org/) 
as to which email clients support which HTML/CSS tags and attributes.

Some other useful links here:

[A Designer's Guide to HTML Email](http://articles.sitepoint.com/print/designers-guide-html-email)
[How to Code HTML Email Newsletters](http://articles.sitepoint.com/print/code-html-email-newsletters)

Answer (score 0):

email clients does not support all html/css features. for example, tables are best for making newsletter.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.  Tables for layout are generally accepted quite well.

Here is a nifty chart that shows what is supported by what clients, as well as market share of each:
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/